# D3 Force Layout / 2 magnets?

Tags: javascript, layout, d3.js

I have a central circle (C1) and have bunch of nodes on the left, marked with 'L' and bunch of them on the right, marked with 'R'. 
I've been trying unsuccessfully implement the following behavior ( for this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/94/   `start();`):

I would like the 'L' marked circles to be dragged by a magnet / force onto the left and the 'R' marked circles to be dragged/ forced onto the right.

Could some please help/ advise or modify my given example with a better idea, please. Of course if there is a better way of doing this Your suggestions are welcome

Comment: The force layout doesn't allow you that amount of fine-grained control. In particular, there's no notion of "left" or "right". [This example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7882658) may help with clustering groups of nodes.

Comment: Thanks for Your comment. It does answer my question but Your suggestions seems a bit blurry

Comment: Well basically what I'm saying is that you can't do that with the force layout, at least not without quite significant modifications.

Comment: Understood :) What Im basically asking is - any suggestions ?

Comment: As a first crude approach, you could simply adjust the positions of the L nodes to the left and the R nodes to the right in each tick.

Comment: Sorry for being a pain, but could You please collaborate more on Your approach and explain how to do it ? Im completely new to this galore of d3 functionality

Comment: In the handler for the `tick` event, you would usually set the position of the nodes (this is what happens in most of the examples). However, you can adjust the values the force layout computed as well. This is what I'm proposing.

Comment: Please excuse my incompetence but,If its not such a huge hassle for You, would it be too much for You to edit my js fiddle ?

Comment: E.g. http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/95/

Comment: witchcraft... Man, the beer is on me ! Going to analysis this.Thanks